# Fill array with web api ajax call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with jQuery or Javascript. I am trying to show more flags in Google maps from an IP array. I managed to pass to the function the IP array, but I have a problem when I calls with ajax the web api as many times as the array length, the result, **locations** array is empty(undefinied);

Here is my code

```
function initialize(ipList)
{
    var locations = [];
    var ips = ipList;
    var apiUrl = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/';


//    for(var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++)
//    {
//        jQuery.ajax
//        ({ 
//            url: apiUrl + ips[i], 
//            type: 'POST', 
//            dataType: 'jsonp',
//            success: function(location) 
//            {
//                if(location != null)
//                {
//                    locations.push(location);;
//                }
//            }
//        });
//    }

    $.each(ips, function(i, x) 
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: apiUrl + x,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                if(data != null)
                {
                    locations[i] = location;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    var properties = 
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0].latitude, locations[0].longitude),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),properties);

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            position:{lat: locations[i].latitude, lng: locations[i].longitude},
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            title: locations[i].city
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to have

```
locations[i] = location;
```

instead of

```
locations[i] = data;
```

?

you probably have a context, scope issue.  When using callbacks, the callback function cannot see the values created by your initialize call.  the quickest solution is to define locations outside of your of initialization.

Comment: also if you are just appending to locations, you cant always do locations[locations.length] =  location; .

Comment: another observation.  Ajax is an async call.  The javascript is not going to stop and wait for your ajax call to answer and populate the array before moving on to the rest of your function.

Comment: I chaged 

locations.push(location);

was what I wanted. Am not a js expert. I know that async will not stop, thats the problem, how to solve that ?!

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested but something more along these lines. I made map a global variable.

```
          var map = null;
            function initialize(ipList) {
                var ips = ipList;
                var apiUrl = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/';

                $.each(ips, function (i, x) {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: apiUrl + x,
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                                porcessPoint(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            function processPoint(datapoint) {
                // assuming the first point is used to create the map
                if (!map) {
                    var properties =
                    {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(datapoint.latitude, datapoint.longitude),
                        zoom: 10,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), properties);
                }

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                ({
                    position: { lat: datapoint.latitude, lng: datapoint.longitude },
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                    title: datapoint.city
                });
                 marker.setMap(map);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for someone. This is how I changed the whole code:

```
$(function() 
{   
    $('#details').hide();
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function()
    {
        var ipInput = $("#ipInput").val();

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/LocationFromIP/public_html/php/traceroute.php',
            data: {param:  ipInput},
            success: function(data)
            {
                var ipList = data.match(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g);
                for(var i = 0; i < ipList.length; i++)
                {
                    $('#details').append(ipList[i] + '<br />');
                }
                initialize(ipList);
                $('#details').show();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
            {
               alert(xhr.status);
               alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }); 
});


function initialize(ipList)
{
    var ips = ipList;
    var apiUrl = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/';

    var map = null;
    $.each(ips, function(i, x) 
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: apiUrl + x,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(location) 
            {
                if (i == 0) 
                {
                    var properties = 
                    {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
                        zoom: 10,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),properties);
                }

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker 
                ({
                    position:{lat: location.latitude, lng: location.longitude},
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                    title: location.city
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }
        });
    });


}
```